# Toggling components multiple times to display different outputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle

I have say 5 buttons, where i want to display different things on click.

Each of the 5 things is its own component. I would like to say click one button, and display one component, but then click another and then remove the previous component and display the other and so on...I want a toggle switch but for the toggle to work if one component is still being displayed.

I have got myself into a pickle and i am displaying all sorts when clicking my buttons this is my main component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import SecondaryButton from '../src/components/buttons/secondaryButton';
import WarningButton from '../src/components/buttons/warningButton';

import AllButtons from '../src/components/allButtons';
import PMPButtons from '../src/components/pmpButtons';

const sectionStyles = 'mt-5 border-b pb-5';

class App extends Component {
  state = { visible: true };
  PMPBtnState = { visible: false };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section id='response' className={sectionStyles}>
          <div className='mt-5 inline-flex space-y-4 flex-wrap'>
            <span></span>
            <WarningButton
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
              }}>
              All
            </WarningButton>
            <SecondaryButton onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}>General</SecondaryButton>
            <SecondaryButton
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ visible: this.PMPBtnState.visible });
              }}>
              PMP
            </SecondaryButton>
            <SecondaryButton onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}>RTB</SecondaryButton>
            <SecondaryButton onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}>VAST</SecondaryButton>
          </div>
        </section>

        {this.state.visible ? <AllButtons /> : null}

        {this.PMPBtnState.visible ? <PMPButtons /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can execute a function in the render section of a React component, make a `display()` function that will display another component depending on a state that is toogle by your different buttons. So, when `dashboardStatus === "component_A"` then your `component_A` will be display.\

Here is (a part of) an example of something similar I did in the past for an admin dashboard:

```js
const Admin = () => {
    const [dashboardStatus, setDashboardStatus] = useState("users");

    const switchDashboard = (x) => {
        setDashboardStatus(x);
    };

    const display = () => {
        if (dashboardStatus === "users") {
            return <UserDashboard />;
        } else if (dashboardStatus === "lessons") {
            return <FormationsDashboard />;
       }
    };

    return (
    <div>
           <button
              onClick={() => switchDashboard("users")}
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
            Utilisateurs
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => switchDashboard("lessons")}
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
            {display()}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks this does the job...had to tweak a few things but all good now